# Error al filtrar dos veces con combobox

Tags: php, mysql

Trato de realizar filtros por carrera, turno y ciclo, con un combobox me sale pero cuando trato de insertar otro y también filtrar el anterior ya no me funcionan, espero me ayuden.

Éste es mi código:

```
<form action="busquedaadmin.php" method="post">
  <select name="filtro"><option value="todos">
    <option value="Ingenieria de Sistemas">Ingenieria de Sistemas</option>
    <option value="Contabilidad">Contabilidad</option></select>
  <select name="filtro2"><option value="todos"></option>
    <option value="Manana">Mañana</option>
    <option value="Noche">Noche</option></select>
  <button type="submit">Filtrar</button></form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['filtro'])){
  $filtro=$_POST['filtro'];
  switch($_POST['filtro']){
    case "todos":
      $sql = "select * from alumnos;";
      break;
    case "Ingenieria de Sistemas":
      $sql = "select * from alumnos WHERE carreraal='$filtro'";
      break;
    case "Contabilidad":
      $sql = "select * from alumnos WHERE carrera='$filtro'";
  }
}
if(isset($_POST['filtro2'])){
  $filtro2=$_POST['filtro2'];
  switch($_POST['filtro2']){
    case "todos":
      $sql = "select * from alumnos;";
      break;
    case "Manana":
      $sql = "select * from alumnos WHERE carreraal='$filtro' AND turnoal='$filtro2'";
      break;
    case "Noche":
      $sql = "select * from alumnos WHERE carreraal='$filtro' AND turnoal='$filtro2'";
      break;
  }
}
else{
  $sql = "select * from alumnos;";
}
$resultado=$mysqli->query($sql);
echo "<center><table><th>Id</th><th>Nombre</th><th>Descripcion</th>   <th>Precio</th><th>Fecha de Registro</th>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
{
  echo "<tr><td>{$row['codal']}</td> ".
       "<td>{$row['nombresal']} </td> ".
       "<td>{$row['apellidosal']} </td> ".
       "<td>{$row['carreraal']} </td> ".
       "<td>{$row['cicloal']} </td> ".
       "<td>{$row['turnoal']} </td></tr>";
} 
echo "</table></center>";
?>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar un poco más tu problema? Realmente sospecho que lo que quieres decir es que solo se ejecuta la segunda sentencia cuando ambos filtros están activos, esto se debe a que si se encuentra el `filtro2` y `filtro1` seleccionados, solo estas recuperando los datos de `filtro2` ya que reescribes la consulta `$sql`. Sinceramente creo que lo que deberías de realizar, si quieres que ambos filtros se realicen, sería hacer una condición `if-elseif-elseif-else` en la que compruebes todas las combinaciones (1 filtro, el otro, ambos o ninguno) pero en las cuales no sobrescribas la `sql`.

Comment: Además, deberías de usar sentencias preparadas ya que si no puedes estar sujeto a `SQL Injection`.

Comment: Recien estoy aprendiendo lo que es programacion y pues espero me puedas ayudar es lo unico que me falta para acabar, y si he escuchado de SQL Injection pero como a que sentencias se refiere, entonces es if del segundo filtro lo cambio por un elseif o falta arreglar mar, mi problema es  que solo ejecuta un combobox quisiera filtrar por esos dos filtros.. pero solo me sale por uno

Comment: ¿Te ejecuta siempre el segundo verdad? Eso es porque la línea `$resultado=$mysqli->query($sql);` está ejecutando la sentencia `$sql`. Si entra en el segundo if, estás sobrescribiendo esta variable con respecto a la primera sentencia. Mira la **[documentación de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.elseif.php)** sobre la condición `if-else if-else`. Yo creo que te puede ayudar bastante ya que está muy bien explicada.

Comment: al momento que puse el elseif en el segundo filtro ahora solo ejecuta el primero, si entiendo lo de if elseif y else, en el documento que me diste: pero el problema esta en el $sql por lo que me dices verdad?

Answer (score 1):

Al darle formato al código se ve más fácil el error. Tal y como lo estás haciendo ahora, esto es lo que ocurre (sé que va a ser algo complejo):

1. Si el primer filtro tiene algún valor, crea la consulta SQL.

---

2. Si el segundo filtro tiene algún valor, crea la consulta SQL.
3. Si no existe un segundo filtro, crea la consulta SQL.

Nota como pongo "crea la consulta" en todos los puntos y no actualiza o extiende, y como pongo una separación entre los puntos 1 y 2 (el si no, aplica sólo al 2, no al 1). Esto es porque **la consulta se reemplaza completamente si se cumple (o no) alguna de las condiciones**. De hecho, **la consulta SQL del primer `if` (el punto 1) nunca debería ejecutarse**, porque al llegar al punto 2, si se cumple la condición la consulta SQL será reemplazada en el `switch`... y si no se cumple, será reemplazada en el `else` (el punto 3).

No sólo eso sino que hay otro fallo. Si el primer filtro (`$_POST['filtro']`) no tiene valor y se pasa al segundo filtro (`$_POST['filtro2']`), deberías recibir un error, porque **estarías usando una variable que no existe (`$filtro`)** que se inicializa en el primer `if` (donde no se entraría).

Y todo esto sin entrar en lo que acertadamente pone Error404 en los comentarios: **este código es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL**. Algo que, aunque pareces no dar importancia, en mi opinión debería ser siempre tu primera prioridad.

Otro *fallo* que hay es que parece que en el segundo filtro, no importa si el turno es mañana o tarde, la consulta SQL es la misma en ambos casos.

---

Mi recomendación sería que si quieres aplicar los dos filtros, en lugar de reescribir la consulta cada vez, lo que hagas fuera extender la consulta con cada filtro. Por ejemplo (y ojo porque este código puede seguir sufriendo problemas de inyección SQL):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE 1=1 ";

if(isset($_POST['filtro'])){
  $filtro=$_POST['filtro'];
  switch($filtro){
    case "Ingenieria de Sistemas":
      $sql = $sql . " AND carreraal='$filtro' ";
      break;
    case "Contabilidad":
      $sql = $sql . " AND carrera='$filtro' ";
  }
}

if(isset($_POST['filtro2'])){
  $filtro2=$_POST['filtro2'];
  switch($filtro2){
    case "Manana":
      $sql = $sql . " AND turnoal='$filtro2'";
      break;
    case "Noche":
      $sql = $sql . " AND turnoal='$filtro2'";
      break;
  }
}
```